# Extracting multiple entries of a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have an array

```
arry = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
```

and I want to get the fourth, second, and seventh element of that array.

Let's say some other function determined which are the needed values and passed me backan array of indices like `[3, 1, 6]`. In most languages I could write this

```
array[3,1,6] #=> ["d","b","g"] (or "dbg"?)
```

or

```
array[3 1 6] #=> ["d","b","g"]
```

But that won't work in Ruby, of course.  Is there a simple way to do this in Ruby?  The cleanest I can find is something like:

```
[3,1,6].map { |i| array[i] }
```

I really tried to find a duplicate to this question since it seems so basic, but I just couldn't.

This is remarkably easy to do in most languages, so I'm almost assuming I'm just overlooking the remarkably obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array.values_at(3,1,6) #=> ["d","b","g"]
```

Comment: Dang it.  Knew it was something simple.  Not as simple as just being a function of [] like I'd assumed, but this is just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your *other function* returns an array then you must flatten it before you can pass it as parameters to `values_at`. Like this

```
arry = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

def indices
  [1,3,6]
end

puts arry.values_at(*indices)
```

**output**

```
b
d
g
```